# Can I build a symbol cleaner plugin?

Tags: adobe-xd

I need to create a list of and on-demand delete unused symbols in my XD document. Do you think it is possible to build a plugin to do this for Adobe XD?

I am a beginner in JavaScript, so I am not able to decide whether such a plugin can even be built. But if there is a capability, I am sure I can build it.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes/no questions are not received well as they are pretty much useless. What if I said "yes"? Now what?  You should [edit] and rewrite your question to say what you've learned via research, and what if anything you have tried, and to ask how it can be done, not whether or not it is possible. How to do it is much more important than "yes."

Comment: "I am sure I can build it" - go ahead... you dont need us to tell you. if other plugins exist "Adobe XD features plugins and app-integrations from Adobe and third-party developers that enhances your design workflow by automating..." then it's possible. go have fun and try

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement Will and Scriptable. I will explore more on this and get back to everyone with the progress.

Answer (score 2):

Global search and delete(replace) is not possible due to the [edit context limitation](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/core/edit-context.html?h=edit%20context). However, if you want to build a plugin that manages objects based on user's [selection](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/selection.html?h=selection), it's totally possible.